# Conversion of number to date affect the performance in oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, date, type-conversion

I have below query where the `DT_ID` is number data type column and the value stored in this column is date in the format `'YYYYMMDD'`.

In my below query I want to get the previous week data from Monday till Sunday for weekly reporting and this query works very fast.

```
select  ID,NAME
from TEST_REPORT
where 
DT_ID between 20170904 and 20170910;
```

But this is hardcoded date and I want to make it dynamic. I tried with this query:

```
select  ID,NAME
from TEST_REPORT
where 
DT_ID>= next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 14 and
          DT_ID< next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 7;
```

But it gives this error:

> expecting Number and got date

When I convert this number to date like below query it's resulting a lot of performance issue. Is there any other way Ican make it dynamic with better performance?

```
select  ID,NAME
from TEST_REPORT
where 
to_date(DT_ID,'YYYYMMDD') >= next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 14 and
          (DT_ID,'YYYYMMDD') < next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 7;
```

Comment: Please show the table definition, and column data types, and example table data.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the date values to strings and then to numbers:

```
select  ID,NAME
from TEST_REPORT
where DT_ID >= to_number (to_char (next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 14,
                           'YYYYMMDD'))
  and DT_ID < to_number (to_char (next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'MONDAY') - 7,
                           'YYYYMMDD'));
```